# Maven error on first step in tutorial

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, pom.xml

I am following a great looking tutorial at: `http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/spring/project`

On step one after copying in the code for the pom.xml, I get 9 errors. Here is the error that shows up on line 1 of my pom.xml:

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.   pom.xml /Guestbook  line 1  Maven Configuration Problem
```

I can post the other errors if necessary. I tried before this to run some simple pre-made maven projects, I believe they call them archtypes. They had similar errors. I don't understand why this is happening and I can't get some hello world thing to not throw errors immediately.

Comment: Simply delete the locale repository .m2/repository and retry it. Are you behind a proxy or something else ?

Comment: I am making this project from home and I should not be behind a proxy. I could not find the .m2 folder. I searched around my eclipse project folder with ls -a.

Comment: I found the .m2 project, deleted it, and then updated my project. All the errors are gone like magic. Thanks :)

Comment: Deleting your .m2 repository is black magic.  The reason it "works" in this case is that it's wiping out the cached artifact resolution failure which persists for 24 hours in maven.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say no to code voodoo.  Don't nuke .m2!

When Maven tries to resolve dependencies for your build, it first looks in the local repository, aka .m2/repository.  If it finds them there, it uses these locally cached artifacts.  If the artifact doesn't exist in the local repository, Maven will attempt to resolve it from the remote repositories it knows about.  Out of the box, it only knows about maven central.  So, it will go there.

There is one major complication to scenario, which you are encountering.  If a given dependency artifact is a SNAPSHOT artifact, then you will want to occassionally check for new versions of that artifact as the SNAPSHOT name is an indication that it is currently under development and could change frequently.  To handle this, Maven is built to check once a day in remote repos for newer versions of any SNAPSHOT artifact that it has in the local repository.

Additionally, if it tries to find an arifact in a remote repository and get's some sort of failure -- commonly due to network relates issues that might be temporary or permanent ( network slowness or proxy set up ) -- this too failure is noted in the local repository meta-data.  Like a SNAPSHOT resolution, this failure will persist as the state of the given artifact for 24 hours.

To override Maven's 24 hour policy, you do not have to nuke your local repository.  You simply pass it the -U flag, which causes it to "update" all local artifact states, i.e. it will go out and recheck remote repositories for everything ( except for successfully resolved release artifacts -- releases are supposed to be permanent ) it knows about.

So, try:

```
mvn -U install
```

Not,

```
rm -Rf .m2
```

Comment: Thank you Chad for your detailed and thoughtful post. I am using M2Eclipse. Is there an equivalent action to mvn -U install that I can perform in my IDE?

Comment: I think you can configure that when you use the run configurations to set up a task that executes a maven build.

Comment: With M2Eclipse you can try: right click on project -> Maven -> Update Maven Project and check "Force update of Snapshot/Releases"

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, right click under your project name, choose popup menu: **Maven->Update Project**. In the following dialog, check "**Force Update of Snapshots/Releases**", click "OK". Then maven will redownload the needed dependencies. Anyway, this solved my problem.[image: Force Update]